# imagemagick данные без заголовка

Tags: imagemagick

Подскажите, какой командой `imagemagick` вытянуть матрицу пикселей из изображения без заголовка данных? Т.е оставить только данные.

Допустим есть изображение 2х2 пикселей (чёрно-белое без оттенков серого). Мне нужно вытянуть только данные. В итоге должно получить 4 бита.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert -list Format` показывает поддерживаемые форматы.
Среди них есть Raw-форматы -- без заголовка.
Файл может иметь такое расширение или можно указать формат через двоеточие перед именем файла:

`convert 4.bmp MONO:4` или `convert 4.bmp 4.mono`

Но в любом случае 4 бита не получится, выдаёт хотя бы 1 байт на каждую строку пикселей.

С некоторыми форматами работает неправильно